# Modx revo обработка формы статичным хуком AjaxForm

Tags: ajax, modx, hook, formit

Есть MODX revo 2.8.1
Есть 2 формы на разных страницах на AjaxForm
Сделал свой хук для обработки данных форм.Хук статичный, т.е. в файле.
Как получить в хуке имя формы и имя страницы с этой формы?
И как получить доступ к объектам MODX?
PS. ID страницы в хук приходит, но в хуке недоступны объекты MODX, только массив $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

В общем пришлось решить проблему таким же способом как и с формой в чистом html: ввел в форму скрытые input для каждой страницы. Получил их в $_POST. А там уже как обычно.